# asp.net images display in ie but not in firefox

Tags: asp.net, image

I've an asp.net image in my webform.

I've set the imageurl as follows

```
Image.Imageurl=".\\Attachments\\Photo-1.jpeg".
```

The problem is that it's working fine in ie but not is mozilla firefox..

Comment: What does the HTML output look like? Why are you using \ instead of `/`, as is standard for URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use backslashes? Try `Image.ImageUrl="/Attachments/Photo-1.jpeg";`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if you can post your html code, then it will be great.
Secondly, Sometimes it also happens, when we missed some html tags to be closed. so kindly check it also, because this could be a simple problem which you have overlooked.